# Do potatoes and rice lose significant amount of fiber when overcooked?

Tags: rice, fiber

I overcooked both brown rice and potatoes today, both boiling. The skin on the potatoes was intact even though I overcooked it but too soft. Does that mean the fiber is significantly reduced in both foods?  Does the fiber leech out into the water?

Comment: Neither of these foods has much fiber to begin with, about 2 and 3 % fiber by weight, according to the first website I found with data. I don't think it was the fiber that was holding them together before they got cooked (but I'll let somone with more knowledge of the actual chemistry post a more definititve answer)

Answer (score 4):

No, fiber is a very hardy beast chemically. There is no fiber lost at all, no matter how much you overcook them in a dish. You would have to throw them into a furnace and take out crisps of carbon no longer recognizable as food to change the fiber.

Comment: does this answer only apply to insoluble fiber or both fibers? I imagine, unlike insoluble fiber, if soluble fiber is boiled or steamed, it will be affected by the water?